# Does Megaera have something to say if Zagreus has no Boons?

Tags: hades

What are the options for Megaera to talk about Zagreus's Boons / Mirror purchases?

I know [she notes the Mirror purchases and if they're immediately removed next fight](https://youtu.be/bwdYL0KFA_U?t=16)...

And that there's [Final Boss Dialogue for No Boons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDQVF_jWUTE)...

I remember hearing about No Boons Megaera having dialogue for that too, but perhaps I'm mistaken?